# Edit text cursor position from one location to another

Tags: android, android-edittext

I am designing an application in which i take phone number of clients. 
I need a code related to the following:
Shift the cursor to another edit text after 10 digits are entered by the client.

Answer (score 4):

Use a TextWatcher:

```
editText1.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
    @Override
    public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {

        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    }

    @Override
    public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int 
        after) {

        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    }

    @Override
    public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {

        if (s.length() == 10) {
             editText2.requestFocus();  
        }
    }
});
```

Comment: you beat me to it!

Comment: @NikosHidalgo How to search from sqlite but?

Comment: @GunjanMehta not sure exactly what you're after. Maybe it's worth asking a new question with more details to it.